# Should I use git-lfs for packages info files?

Tags: node.js, git, go, dependency-management, git-lfs

As a developer working with several languages, I notice that in most modern languages, dependencies metadata files can change a lot.

For instance, in NodeJS (which in my opinion is the worst when it comes to package management), a change of dependencies or in the version of NPM (respectively yarn) version can lead to huge changes in `package-lock.json` (respectively `yarn.lock`), sometimes with tens of thousands of modified lines.

In Golang for instance, this would be `go.sum` which can have important changes (in smaller  magnitude when compared to Node of course) when modifying dependencies or running `go mod tidy` at times.

Would it be more efficient to track these dependencies files with `git-lfs`? Is there a reason not to do it?

Even if they are text files, I know that it is advised to push SVG files with `git-lfs`, because they are mostly generated files and their diff has no reason to be small when regenerating them after a change.

Are there studies about what language and what size/age of a project that makes `git-lfs` become profitable?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be more efficient to track these dependencies files with git-lfs?

Git does a pretty good job at compressing text files, so initially you probably wouldn't see much gains. If the file gets heavily modified often, then over time the total cloneable repo size would increase by less if you use Git LFS, but it may not be worth it compared to the total repo size increases, which could make the size savings negligible as a percentage. The primary use case for LFS is largish binary files that change often.

> Is there a reason not to do it?

If you aren't already using Git LFS, I wouldn't recommend starting for this reason. Also, AFAIK there isn't native built in support for diffing versions of files stored in LFS, though workarounds exist. If you often find yourself diffing the files you are considering moving into LFS, the nominal storage size gain may not be worth it.

Comment: Disclaimer: I realize I didn't answer your last question, "Are there studies about what language and what size/age of a project that makes git-lfs become profitable?" I don't have any data or experience on tracking largish text files in LFS.

Comment: However today there are very few projects where I don't need to use LFS. There are always images or binary, or generated text files for a reason or another (documentation, generated mocks, etc).